# Questions About Authentication and Web API

Tags: c#, angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to create a layer for my Web API 2 Odata4 application to abstract the details of authentication so an end user can bolt on whichever Auth provider they choose.  Right now the application is structured to authenticate the user in the UI using Microsoft B2C and redirect the user accordingly to the Angular2 page.  All of the redirect logic to and from B2C is hard coded into the UI.  At that point the token is extracted from the URL and is decoded as necessary to get username and ClientID information.  When the UI makes a call to the API it passes that username and ClientID to the service which implements OAuth.  The API matches the client ID with the acceptable list and serves data accordingly.  Most of this process seems hard coded into both the UI and the API.

This is how the UI is grabbing the token:

```
sharedservice.id_token = location.hash.split('id_token=')[1];
authService.isLoggedIn = true;
fetch(sharedservice.JWKS_URL, {
    method: 'GET'
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
    this.getSigningKey(json.keys[0].kid, ()=>{})
})
```

This should only happen if the auth service has successfully authenticated the user.  The token is then validated and the user information is setup.

The API gets the authentication service setup in the startup.auth.cs file under app_start and it looks like this:

```
 // These values are pulled from web.config
        public static string AadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];
        public static string Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];
        public static string ClientId1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];
        public static string ClientId2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];
        public static string ClientId3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];
        public static string ClientId4 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];
        public static string SignUpSignInPolicy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" "];

        public static string DefaultPolicy = SignUpSignInPolicy;

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(CreateBearerOptionsFromPolicy(DefaultPolicy));
        }

        private OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions CreateBearerOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
        {
            var metadataEndpoint = string.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, policy);

            TokenValidationParameters tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // Accept only those tokens where the audience of the token is equal to the client ID of this app
                ValidAudiences = new string[] { ClientId1, ClientId2, ClientId3, ClientId4 },
                //ValidAudience = ClientId2,
                AuthenticationType = Startup.DefaultPolicy
            };

            return new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
                AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(metadataEndpoint))
            };
        }
```

All of the B2C configuration seems to be hard coded.  What is the most acceptable way to abstract all of this information out so the app can integrate with whatever service the end user cares to use and not just B2C?  I would assume such a solution would require changes to both the Angular 2 pages and the API.